# Jsonconvert.deserialize generic list type bug?

Tags: json, list, generics, types, deserialization

I'm using

```
List<T> mylist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(instring);
```

to deserializeobject (and use this generic type routine frequently for many data types).  I hit one that's giving me the error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NetRestSqlApi.Models.CA_Users]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])...

The data is correct.  If I deserialize keying in the object instead of using Generic type T it works fine.

```
List<NetRestSqlApi.Models.CA_Users> mylist1 =
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NetRestSqlApi.Models.CA_Users>>(instring);
```

I'm at a loss.  I'm using latest newtonsoft 10.0.3.  I've debugged and verified T is the same exact Object/Model as I'm hard-coding above.

I can sit and play with parameters (which I've done) but at the end of the day based on other posts, I'm thinking this deserialize should work same for both.  I don't see any problems with data and can deserialize in notepad++ and when I look at it it's all correct.

Are there further diagnostics or workarounds besides hardcoding I can try?

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I found it.  I wish I had a person to look over my shoulder and tell me what dumb thing I've done this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian, but I found it.    I added.

if (typeof(T)== typeof(CA_Users))

and found I was passing a list into T instead of the object.  So in debug it looked right, but wasn't.  Thanks for the help.